# Merging bunch of tracks into fewer?

Tags: merge, gpx, overpass-turbo

The following OverpassTurbo query for train routes in Sicily, Italy, returns ten's of tiny tracks:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];

//Sicily: 39152
rel(39152);map_to_area -> .searchArea;

(
  node["railway"="rail"](area.searchArea);
  way["railway"="rail"](area.searchArea);
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I was wondering if there were a way to somehow merge them so that I end up with much fewer?

The goal is to get a GPX file that contains all the train routes displayed in the Transport Map available on OSM.org:
[image]

Actually, it's a lot more than "ten's of tracks": The query above returns… 4,158 occurences of "<trk>".

--

Edit: [Drawing the routes manually](https://github.com/unmonastery/matera-gtfs/wiki/How-to-build-routes-with-JOSM) isn't very smart, but it does the job